# Java toJson (Gson)

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to save my deck object in my Json file, I'm using gson.toJson (obj, new FileWriter ("D: \ file.json")); but when I run the code, it erases all my json file.
There is my  code :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    String res  = JsonTransform.readFromFile("/json.json", true);
    Deck newDeck = gson.fromJson(res, Deck.class);
    System.out.println(newDeck);

    System.out.println("Do you want to add question ? enter 1 for yes and 2 for no");
    answer = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    while(answer==1) {

        System.out.println("Please enter the author");
        author=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the category");
        category=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the statement");
        statement=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the answer");
        answ=sc.nextLine();

        Question q = new Question(author,category,statement,answ);
        newDeck.createQuestion(q);
        System.out.println("Do you want to add again a new Question ? enter 1 for yes and 2 for no");
        answer=sc.nextInt();
    }


    try {
        System.out.println(newDeck);
        gson.toJson(newDeck, new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\flori\\workspace\\Projet_Q2\\src\\json.json"));
    } catch (JsonIOException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

thank ;)

Comment: Of course. If you save an image you drew over an image you've drawn before, it doesn't add to the image, it overwrites the file.

Comment: in fact , that write nothing in my Json file and cleaning all the file

Comment: You're not closing the file. Amateur mistake with basic IO.

Comment: that as that ,thank

Answer (score 0):

Use [`new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\flori\\workspace\\Projet_Q2\\src\\json.json", true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) if you want to append.